# change the category of a post before it is saved/published

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

A user creates a new standard-post. If he forgot to add his category i want my script to add it for him. 
To test this i first wanted to change all non matching posts-categories in the category "test".

```php
function change_cat($data, $postarr){

    $author_role = "test"; 
    $data["post_category"] = $author_role; // seems not working

    return $data;
}
add_filter("wp_insert_post_data", "change_cat", 99 , 2);
```

At the moment unfortunately this script stops all posts and changes.

edit: reason for not using the default option in settings: i want to different roles replacing test later on.

Comment: In the Wordpress settings you can set the default category if not selected.

Comment: @DanielVickers Thanks for pointing that out. I failed to mention that i might want to add different categories depending on roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to set the post category to "test" for standard posts if not selected**

To do this we will have to get the current post ID and update the category only if it is a standard post and has not got a category already on saving of the post.

```
<?php function set_default_category($post_ID){

    if(wp_is_post_autosave($post_ID) || wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
        return;
    } //If this is just an autosave or post revision, don't do anything

    $postFormat = get_post_format( $post_ID ); //Get the post format of current post

    if( !empty( $postFormat ) ) {
        return;
    } //If post is not a standard format, don't do anything

    $currentCat = get_the_category(); //Get the current set Category
    $defaultCat = get_cat_ID( "test" ); //Get ID of "test" category

    if( empty( $currentCat ) ) { //Check if category is set
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $defaultCat );  //Set the current post ID's Category to "test"
    }

} add_action('save_post', 'set_default_category');?>
```

**This hasn't been tested, but in theory should work. Let me know any errors you get if it does not so I can amend.**

Answer (score 0):

I think `post_category` in `wp_insert_post_data` should be array. Check docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

```
function book_save( $data, $postarr ) {
    // check what we save before changes
    if ( ! isset($_POST['post_type']) || $_POST['post_type'] != 'post' ) return $data;
    if ( get_current_screen()->id != 'post' ) return $data;
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE  ) return $data;
    if ( ! current_user_can('edit_post', $postarr['ID'] ) ) return $data;

    // all ok let's check post category
    if ( empty($data['post_category']) ) {
        $data['post_category'] = array(12, 20); // array with category IDs
    }

    return $data;
}
add_action('wp_insert_post_data', 'book_save', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: This doesn’t check if the post format is standard, and also it doesn’t have anything regarding setting all posts to “test”

Comment: @daniel-vickers can you please point where butterfly15 is asking about post format in his question?

Comment: “A user creates a new standard-post” standard refers to the post format in WordPress :)

Comment: It seems that $data['post_category'] is not given in https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data only $postarr  contains 'post_category' ...